# Using CSS selectors to apply bottom border to select cells

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I use pseudo class selectors (as opposed to class selectors) to apply the bottom border to only those cells where the text "meh" occurs?

Here's my current SASS/CSS along with an example of how it should look below it:

http://jsfiddle.net/keruilin/4THpE/37/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:contains()` jQuery-only pseudo-selector:

```
$('td:contains("meh")').addClass('bordered');​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4THpE/21/**

---

If you want to select the cells whose text is *exactly* `meh`, you have to do something a bit different:

```
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'meh';
}).addClass('bordered');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4THpE/23/**

Comment: Blender, I can see how using jQuery this way would work.  I did update my question to provide some clarification.

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS, though, unless they reintroduce `:contains()` to the spec, which isn't likely.

Comment: Hmm...that stinks.  In my actual markup, not every cell will contain 'meh' to make using jQuery so easy.  Looks like I'll have to programmatically figure it out nonetheless.

Comment: Are the cells that contain `meh` every other row? If so, you can just use `tr:nth-child(odd)` to select them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

***JQuery CODE***

```
$("td:contains('meh')").addClass("border-style");
```

**OR**

```
$(".border-style").css("border-bottom", "1px solid red");
```